# rostest - Executable not rebuilding

Tags: ros, catkin, rostest, gtest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to write rostests for the clear_costmap_recovery package. [[relevant code]](https://github.com/DLu/navigation/tree/clear_recovery_array/clear_costmap_recovery)

Is there a way to build the tests for only one package?

Running `catkin_make` or `catkin_make clear_costmap_recovery` do not rebuild the test executable.

Running `catkin_make run_tests` does rebuild the test executable, but also runs ALL the tests in the navigation package.

Running `catkin_make run_tests_clear_costmap_recovery` runs only the relevant tests, but does NOT rebuild the test executable.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185600/rostest---executable-not-rebuilding/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2014-07-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you can do it like this:

```
catkin_make tests
catkin_make run_tests_clear_costmap_recovery
```

Those targets can probably share the same command line.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-07-09**:
Good call. And yes, they can share the same line. Thanks joq.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-07-09**:
Although, wouldn't you think that run_tests_clear_costmap_recovery would build the tests if run_tests does?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-07-10**:
`run_tests` depends on `tests`, but the package-specific ones don't. That may have been a conscious choice. It can sometimes be useful, once you understand how it works.